# Play an audio file from a incoming file without saving

Tags: php, html, ringcentral

I'm using the ringcentral-php SKD to retrieve call recordings. I'm attempting to get around saving the file before playing it. (Stream or play from temp file) This is the code.

```
$uri = 'https://media.devtest.ringcentral.com/restapi/v1.0/account/851921005/recording/15694407005/content';

$apiResponse = $platform->get($uri);

$mp3_file = $apiResponse->raw();

file_put_contents("recordings/recording_test.mp3", $mp3_file);//This is not allowed on the server//

echo '<audio controls>
<source src="recordings/recording_test.mp3" type="audio/mpeg">
    </audio>';
```

The goal is not to save the recordings, just play them on demand. Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Concept

You can output content directly to the browser with PHP. Instead of saving the file to disk, you'll send it as a response to the client's browser with headers.

---

### Static

get_audio.php:

```
$uri = 'https://media.devtest.ringcentral.com/restapi/v1.0/account/851921005/recording/15694407005/content';
$apiResponse = $platform->get($uri);
$mp3_file = $apiResponse->raw();

header('Content-Type: audio/mpeg');

echo $mp3_file;
```

HTML:

```
<audio controls>
    <source src="get_audio.php" type="audio/mpeg">
</audio>
```

---

### Dynamic

And of course you can pass parameters if you need to adjust which audio file to output dynamically:

get_audio.php:

```
if (!isset($_GET['audioId'])) {
    // Handle the error appropriately in production of course
    die('Audio ID is required');
}

$audioId = $_GET['audioId'];
$uri = 'https://media.devtest.ringcentral.com/restapi/v1.0/account/851921005/recording/' . $audioId . '/content';

$apiResponse = $platform->get($uri);
$mp3_file = $apiResponse->raw();

header('Content-Type: audio/mpeg');

echo $mp3_file;
```

HTML:

```
<audio controls>
    <source src="get_audio.php?audioId=15694407005" type="audio/mpeg">
</audio>
```